# How to merge models in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 models and I want to merge and filter them out by its ids. I have read in docs that there is an `expand` method and also it has `where` method for filtering items by their id's. How can i do it properly?

Now I do this:

```
 List<ScheduleVariants> sheduler =
        Provider.of<List<ScheduleVariants>>(context)
            .expand((element1) => cards)
            .expand((element2) => stops)
            .where((element3) => element3.stId == stId)
            .toList();

List<RaceCard> cards = Provider.of<List<RaceCard>>(context);
List<Stop> stops =  Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context);
```

I want tp get all filtered elements from the last list which is  `List<Stop> stops =  Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context);` and for achiving this goal I need to filter all elements through ScheduleVariants, RaceCard, Stops simultaneously.

The classes:

```
class RaceList {
  RaceList({
    this.mvId,
    
  });

 @required final int mvId;
}
class Routes {
  Routes({
    this.mrId,

  });
  final int mrId;

class Stop {
  Stop({
    this.stId,
    this.stTitle,
    
  });

  @required final int stId;
}

class ScheduleVariants {
  ScheduleVariants({
    this.mvId,
    this.mrId,
  });

  @required final int mvId;
final int mrId;
}
```

Comment: accept my answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expand` is not a solution for this,

Since the classes are not extending an interface with property `stId`, you should filter them individually and then put them together

```
    final List<RaceCard> cards = Provider.of<List<RaceCard>>(context);
    final List<Stop> stops = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context);
    final variants = Provider.of<List<ScheduleVariants>>(context);

    final List<dynamic> scheduler = [
      ...cards.where((x) => x.stId == stId),
      ...stops.where((x) => x.stId == stId),
      ...variants.where((x) => x.stId == stId)
    ];
```

###### If classes are inheriting an interface to have `stId`

Let's say your classes look like this

```
class Indexable {
 final String stId;
  Indexable({
    required this.stId,
  });
}
class Stop extends Indexable{
...
}

class RaceCard extends Indexable {
...
}

class ScheduleVariants extends Indexable{
...
}
```

Then you can put them in a `List<Indexable>` and then filter them

```
    final List<RaceCard> cards = Provider.of<List<RaceCard>>(context);
    final List<Stop> stops = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context);
    final variants = Provider.of<List<ScheduleVariants>>(context);
    final List<Indexable> scheduler = <Indexable>[
      ...cards,
      ...stops,
      ...variants
    ].where((element) => element.stId == stId).toList();
```